# Swap an item in list of list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, swap

Given the list puzzle above, I need to be able to swap the position of X to left, right, top or bottom. The question is, how do I swap it with the item beside or in the other list in the list puzzle?

```
puzzle = [[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4'],
          [' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8'],
          [' 9', '10', '11', '12'],
          ['13', '14', '15', ' X']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#generic swap puzzle[a][b] with puzzle[c][d]
puzzle[a][b], puzzle[c][d] = puzzle[c][d], puzzle[a][b]
```

Comment: but the position of X keep changing. and the position of the item beside X keep changing as well. How do I keep track of the changes, and whenever I call my method,it will change to left?

Comment: Do you know the positions of the items you have to swap? Or at least the value of the items?

Comment: ok say I know the initial position of X is [3][3], and i wanted to swap it with 15 which position at [3][2].
When i call the swap method,it swap places correctly using the generic swap u just mentioned.
But after that, i want to swap X with 14. But the position of X is different. How can i swap X with 14, then 13 whenever i call the method?

Comment: Keep track of X's current position. If you know it any time, you can track it all along. So if X at [3][3] is swapped with 15 at [3][2], you can store 3,2. 
How and where? Depends on your program. Could be a global variable or a wrapper function that's calling these swaps could keep track of it.